# What is the growth of this program? ChatGPT is wrong, right?

Tags: algorithm, performance

This is definitely a stupid, and simple question. But for some reason this is bugging me. This is not a homework question--insofar, as I am not solving a homework question for my own work. I am a mathematician, who's helping his friend with some of his math homework for his CS degree. And I am pretty certain I have the correct solution, but ChatGPT gives a different solution. And he wants to follow ChatGPT's solution, when I'm pretty sure it is wrong.

The pseudo code is simple

```
l=0
while n >= 1 do
  for j=1, n, do
    l = l+2
  od
  n = n/3
od
```

ChatGPT has said that this is O(n^2 log(n)), and that just doesn't make sense to me. It's explanation is also kind of nonsense. But my friend seems to be leaning toward ChatGPT, which I think is bull shit. I believe the correct bound is O(nlog(n)), and I've supplied the following reasoning.

The operation:

```
while n >= 1 do
   n = n/3
od
```

grows likes `O(log(n)`. The act of adding a for loop, as the one I used, looks like:

```
Sum_{j=1}^{log(n)} O(n/3^j)
```

This entire sum of operations, just becomes O(nlog(n))...

I'm pretty confident ChatGPT is wrong in this scenario, but I'd appreciate someone more well versed in this kind of stuff. I don't translate code to O notation at all in my work. If I'm wrong that's fine, but I'd appreciate a well thought out answer. For god's sakes, this program has me checking my sanity!

Comment: I haven't taken the time to grok the code yet, but you might want to point your friend to [this discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) about why answers from ChatGPT are banned on Stack Overflow. TL:DR; ChatGPT is very good at producing answers that sound plausible but are actually wrong.

Comment: As a mathematician, you should be able to analyze and rewrite the problem. The for loop and while loop can be replaced with a formula of O(1) complexity.

Comment: @striplingWarrior Yes, I knew ChatGPT was wrong, I just didn't have the capability to prove it to my friend. But I was 80-90% sure my solution was correct....

Comment: The tight upper bound is O(n). The running time is a geometric series: `1+3+9+27+ ... +N`. That is easily proven to be less than `2N`.

Comment: @stephenquan As I agree with you; this isn't the point of the assignment. We can reduce the problem at hand to a shorter running program. That's not the point, the question is how fast does this specific program run. We can obviously reduce this into O(1) by just doing some arithmetic.

Comment: A recent [study on arkiv of ChatGPT](https://arxiv.org/abs/2301.13867v1) is revealing. (Gary Marcus's comment was something like "What do you expect? It can't even count.")

Answer (score 2):

### Update

I realize I may have spoken too soon to say whether `O(n * log n)` is the right answer. It's certainly a lot closer to a right answer than `O(n² * log n)`.

### Original answer

<strike>You are right. ChatGPT is wrong. Your logic is sound. You've got an `O(n)` operation nested inside an `O(log n)` operation, which comes out to `O(n * log n)`.</strike>

This should not come as a surprise: ChatGPT is designed to write prose, and has a consistent track record of making a very convincing case for "facts" and solutions that are simply wrong. Your friend should get out of the habit of relying on ChatGPT for their homework answers for this reason, even if they're ignoring the ethics of the matter.

Comment: Thanks, so much. I knew I was right, but then talking to him, and mostly his friends who found O(n^2 logn) through ChatGPT I wasn't sure. Especially because this isn't my field of mathematics. Don't worry, my friend does all his work well and true in an honest manner. He was just confused because ChatGPT said something different. And I'm too dumb to correct the AI in this manner. Thanks so much.

Comment: I think this is still a very loose bound. The number of operations in the for loop is `n` the first iteration, then `n/3` in the second, then `n/9`, then `n/27` etc. Sum all of those `1/3^i` factors up, and the limit is 1.5. This whole thing is just O(n).

Comment: @RichardDiagram: you can also check out the [SO policy on content *writen by ChatGPT*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy). It doesn't apply in this case of course, but the whole "looks close enough to correct to fool those who don't know better" part definitely is something to be aware of.

Comment: @JoachimSauer See that was it for me! This isn't my forte as a mathematician. But I knew ChatGPT was "lying" in so many words. I knew it was wrong. But I'm just not well versed enough to debunk it, in these types of mathematics. I've been seeing this all the time though with people trying to solve advanced problems in mathematics and ChatGPT literally produces garbage, lmfao.

Comment: @moreON then how do you account for the sum up to \(\log(n)/log(3)\) from the while loop?

Comment: @RichardDiagram you add `O(log(n)) + O(n)` and get `O(n)`

Comment: The first two sentences in this answer are wrong. OP and the bot are equally correct, or equally wrong. The tight upper bound is O(n). Both OP and the bot chose looser upper bounds. Because of the way big-O is defined, neither is technically wrong, but for any practical purpose, neither is right.

Comment: @moreON: You're probably right about that: I don't know if I ever fully understood how the tightness of bounds impacts questions like this. I'd be happy to up-vote an answer to that effect if you add it. I don't know that I could do it justice. I'd take a lot more convincing to believe user3386109's assertion.

Comment: @moreON well that's just wrong, even I know that. We are taking a sum of ```log(n)``` terms of ```O(n)```.  which is ```O(nlog(n))```. This is a multiplicative operation, not additive. We can reduce the program to ```O(n)```, but that doesn't change the value of the program I wrote.....

Comment: @RichardDiagram: I wouldn't discount it too quickly. The inner loop isn't strictly `O(n)`: it's `O(n)` on the first iteration, but it quickly dwindles to `O(1)`. So if on average it's closer to `O(1)` than `O(n)` that would make sense to me. I think I spoke too soon.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior I appreciate your answer, and that my program can be reduced to a simpler program which runs ```O(n)```--that was not the point though. The point was to check whether this specific program runs at this speed, and you answered. If we speed up the code of this program, getting ```O(n)``` is easy.

Comment: @RichardDiagram but it's not `O(log(n))` `O(n)` operations. The first iteration is `n` operations, the second is `n/3`, the third `n/9` ... Naively multiplying the number of iterations by the longest iteration doesn't capture this - you have to sum the geometric series carefully.

Comment: @MoreON YEsss...... how many terms do you sum? You sum ```log_3(n)``` terms, of ```n/3^i```, which equals ```nlogn```.....

Comment: The limit of the sum of the infinite geometric series from i = 0 to positive infinity of `n/3^i` is just `1.5n`. That's the total operations executed by the `for` loop across all of the iterations of the `while` loop. (technically, fewer than the entire infinite series sum are actually executed due to floor division and stopping) - clearly that's `O(n)`. It doesn't need to be multiplied by the number of `while` loop iterations, it's already summed over all of them. To account for checking the while loop, and decreasing the variable, there's also constant operations per iteration.

Comment: @moreOn, let's play this out... Using your terms. We can write ```i=0``` which goes to ```i=1000000000```. Then quite clearly we have ```sum O(n/3^i)``` is ```O(n)```. Whether you are doing this intentionally, or whether you are forgetting. There is a while loop ```while n >= 1 do n = n/3 od``` which appears in this code--which grows like ```log_3 n```. And it appears one level above. This reduces into: ```sum_{i=1}^{log_3 n} O(n/3^i)```. You have completely ignored this log, whether intentionally, or because there exists a speed up which can ignore this log....

Comment: If I understand what you mean by that function that you've just written: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum+from+i%3D1+to+log3%28n%29+of+%28n%2F3%5Ei%29 - it is linear.

Comment: @moreON Okay, I see my confusion. I apologize for being a jack ass. It's fucking linear. To me, the best bound you could get is ```O(nlog(n))```, but the asymptotic bound is linear. I apologize tenfold! You're right!

Answer (score 2):

This question was answered by @moreON but I will present the answer properly, as I see it. Thank you @StriplingWarrior, you definitely quenched my fears that I was so off. I knew it was at least `O(n log(n))`, but the correct answer is `O(n)`. Which you identified before me, after @moreON's comments.

The program `f` which takes `n` and gives `l` is given as:

```
l = 0
while n >=1 do
   for k=1, k <= n, do
       l = l+2
   od
   n = n/3
od
```

The time it takes to run this program, if we treat each single operation as `O(1)`--looks exactly like the equation:

```
sum_{i=1}^{log_3(n)} n/3^i
```

When we consider the growth in `n`. This comes about from the `while` loop doing about `log_3(n)` loops. From here, we do a while loop for at least `1 <= m = n/3`. This does, for each term in the `log_3(n)` list, a larger division by three, `n/3^i`. We can write the growth in cpu time to evaluate `n` of `f`

```
sum_{i=1}^{log_3(n)} n/3^i = n O(1)
```

As a mathematician I should've seen this. But even if I did, I'd doubt that it's that easy. Or as simple as that. Just a bound on a relatively simple sum. I thought, at best we can rough bound it with `O(nlog n)`. But, we can prove that the solution to our problem is:

```
f(n) = O(n)
```

I want to thank @moreON and @StriplingWarrior. You guys were right... I apologize for being a jack ass.